# HAML converts my code into wrong HTML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm writing HAML code:

```
.col-xs-4.form-control= text_field_tag :q
```

But this converts to:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 form-control">
    <input type="text" name="q" id="q">
</div>
```

How can I write HAML that it will convert it to:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="q" placeholder="Email">
```

I cannot find any good documentation for that.

Comment: it's because you are reading wrong documentation. Read the one on `text_field_tag`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is actually this:

```
.col-xs-4.form-control
  = text_field_tag :q
```

That ends up nesting the `text_field_tag` HTML inside of the other `<div>` that you've declared implicitly.

The Rails view helpers like `text_field_tag` are unaware of what DOM context they're being called in, so if you want to add classes you have to pass those through as explicit arguments:

```
= text_field_tag(:q, nil, class: 'col-xs-4 form-control')
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that I can write in that way! Now I know!